# WPF C# Scrollviewer is disabling toolbar buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, button, toolbar, scrollviewer

I am creating a C# WPF application. I have placed a Scrollviewer inside a grid cell. When the application is runnning, if I click anywhere inside the Scrollviewer cell, all of my toolbar buttons, which are located in a different cell and controlled by a different User Control suddenly get disabled and don't get re-enabled.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Thanks for any help.

Here is my ScrollViewer code:

```
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                      Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <StackPanel x:Name="innerPanel" Grid.Column="1" 
                        Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

And my ToolBar code:

```
   <ToolBarTray Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="LightGray" >
        <ToolBar x:Name="toolbar" Background="LightGray" ToolBarTray.IsLocked="False">
            <Button Command="New" Content="New" />
            <Button Command="Open" Content="Open" />
            <Button Command="Save" Content="Save" />
            <Button Command="Cut" Content="Cut" />
            <Button Command="Copy" Content="Copy" />
            <Button Command="Paste" Content="Paste" />
            <Button Command="Record" Content="Record" />
            <Button Command="Play" Content="Play" />
            <Button Command="Pause" Content="Pause" />
            <Button Command="Stop" Content="Stop" />
            <Image Width="20" Margin="5,0"  Source="C:\VolumeIcon1.png"/>
            <Slider x:Name="VolumeControl" Maximum="100" Width="250"  
                    TickPlacement="BottomRight" Foreground="DarkGray" 
                    TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=VolumeControl, Path=Value, 
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                     TextAlignment="Right" Width="30" 
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
```

Here are some images of the buttons when they are disabled vs enabled.

[image]
[image]

Edit:
These four files should reproduce a basic version of the problem I am having. When the Scrollviewer area gets clicked, the new button in my toolbar gets disabled and grayed out.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="UIMilestone.MainWindow" x:Name="window"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UIMilestone"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    SizeChanged="OnWindowSizeChanged"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Background="LightGray">
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid" ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="row0" Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer     HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                      Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace UIMilestone
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        //Links C# project to methods in c++

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mainGrid.Measure(new Size(800, 450));
            mainGrid.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 800, 450));

            TopToolbars tools = new TopToolbars(this);
            mainGrid.Children.Add(tools);

        }

        protected void OnWindowSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

TopToolBars.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="UIMilestone.TopToolbars"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UIMilestone"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="47" d:DesignWidth="790">
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="New" CanExecute="New_CanExecute" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="327.333"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="462.667"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ToolBar x:Name="toolbar" Background="LightGray" ToolBarTray.IsLocked="False">
        <Button Command="New" Content="New" />
    </ToolBar>
</Grid>
```

TopToolBars.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace UIMilestone
{
public partial class TopToolbars : UserControl
{
    private MainWindow win;

    public TopToolbars(MainWindow mainWindowInst)
    {
        win = mainWindowInst;
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
        this.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
    }

    private void New_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "controlled by a different User Control"?

Comment: I have a toolbars partial class that manages the buttons it has its own corresponding User Control xaml file. I am not sure exactly how to explain it as I am fairly new to using wpf. This link explains it better. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_custom_controls.htm

Comment: I tried it as you described, adding a TextBox in your innerPanel. The clipboard commands behave exaclty as they should (e.g. after entering and selecting some text, the Cut and Copy buttons got enabled). So please post some minimum, complete code allowing to reproduce your problem,

Comment: I have added some code that should reproduce a simple version of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because a routed command starts its journey at the element with the focus, bubbling up the visual tree. Your toolbar element is however not in the parent chain of the innerPanel.

Option 1: explicitly specify the toolbar element as command target: Add CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:TopToolbar}}" to your button

Option 2: put your command binding in the MainWindow.

Option 3: Use MVVM: create an ICommand property in your view model and Command="{Binding MyCommand}" in the button